# AWS OpenSearch (Elasticsearch): Reading search times in dashboard monitor, Search latency

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, opensearch

I'm trying to understand what's causing spikes of slow searches on AWS Opensearch (ElasticSearch). Search times are typically 40-150 ms, but I see spikes of searches taking 5-15 *seconds*.

For now, I'm trying to understand how to read the monitors.

In the AWS dashboard, I'm looking at the **Search latency** monitor. It's described as "The average time that it takes a shard to complete a search operation." I see the spikes there. There are various drop-down options for Statistic. When I choose Maximum, the maximum shown during that bad spiking time is about 3000 ms. (Frankly, not sure how I can have an "average" of a "maximum".)

I also monitor the **"took" value** that is returned for every query search. Elasticsearch describes took as "Milliseconds it took Elasticsearch to execute the request." Here I'm seeing the 10+ second times. This also fits with what I'm actually measuring time wise, comparing times before and after I make the request.

So, why doesn't the dashboard monitor show the actual times? Is there a way for me to see it there?

I'm thinking of setting ES_SEARCH_TIMEOUT to a couple of seconds or so. No one is going to wait longer than that for a result, anyway. I think perhaps the slow searches build up, causing more slow searches. Better to have some early errors, hopefully preventing more slow queries. (Although not certain  that this actually stops the query from continuing on the server.)   (Considering options before I pay $600 a month more for the next larger instance size). But if AWS somehow sees 10 second searches as taking 3 seconds, then I'm not sure how to set it.